# Shading area under the curve (KDE) with 2 subplots

Tags: python, kernel-density

guys!

Any ideas how to shade area under the curve with 2 subplots?

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(11, 4.5))
N = 500
X = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, int(0.3 * N)),
                    np.random.normal(5, 1, int(0.7 * N))))

sns.kdeplot(data=X, linewidth=2, fill=True, ax=axs[0])
sns.ecdfplot(X, stat='proportion', ax=axs[1])

plt.show()
```

Like it's done here, only with one plot:

```
np.random.seed(123)
sns.kdeplot(data=data, linewidth=2, fill=True)
ax = sns.kdeplot(data)

kde_lines = ax.get_lines()[-1]
kde_x, kde_y = kde_lines.get_data()
mask = (kde_x > 1.8) & (kde_x < 3.2)
filled_x, filled_y = kde_x[mask], kde_y[mask]
ax.fill_between(filled_x, y1=filled_y)

plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance!

I'm facing the problem with `axs[0].get_lines()[-1]` -> `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your working example, `sns.kdeplot` is called twice, one with `fill=True`, once without.

Hence, to get the subplot-version working, you will have to to the same in order to get a handle to the line in the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(123)
N = 500
data = np.concatenate(
    (
        np.random.normal(0, 1, int(0.3 * N)),
        np.random.normal(5, 1, int(0.7 * N)),
    )
)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(11, 4.5))
N = 500
X = np.concatenate(
    (np.random.normal(0, 1, int(0.3 * N)), np.random.normal(5, 1, int(0.7 * N)))
)

sns.kdeplot(data=X, linewidth=2, fill=True, ax=axs[0])

# repeat kdeplot without fill=True to get a line handle
sns.kdeplot(X, ax=axs[0])

sns.ecdfplot(X, stat="proportion", ax=axs[1])
kde_lines = axs[0].get_lines()[-1]
kde_x, kde_y = kde_lines.get_data()
mask = (kde_x > 1.8) & (kde_x < 3.2)
filled_x, filled_y = kde_x[mask], kde_y[mask]
axs[0].fill_between(filled_x, y1=filled_y)

plt.show()
```

[image]